# How to store data points using lasso select and store them in python?

Tags: bokeh

Tried using bokeh library but when comes the storing part it's not working.

Lasso selection is working but how to store those selected points. I have tried CustomJS but it can't run the python code .

Comment: Please post a minimal code example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In this post i shared a working example similar to what you are trying:

[Write down Bokeh plot selected data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021333/write-down-bokeh-plot-selected-data-not-working)